# Patient-Docter Model: How to Keep Random Generated Keys of an Array, for 12 Hours before new Keys are Echoed?

Tags: php, arrays, list, random, key

Imagine a patient who has eaten too much meat, drunken too much booze and now stuck with a weight problem. Coming back from the docter, he looks at the prescription from the doctor:  *`Choose Three Types of Fruit, and Eat this All-Fruit Diet for 12 hours without putting anything else in your mouth.`* Consistancy is important: just those Exact Three Types are allowed within the 12 hours period, in the same order as is prescribed.

After the 12 hours have passed, the docter will prescribe again 3 new types of fruit, again a random combination from a list of allowed fruits. (Since the list is very very long, virtually no chance of verlap is expected with previous prescription, if overlap does occur, then so be it). The allowed fruits will come from a specially prepared array by the docter e.g.:

```
$fruits = array('Mango', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Coconut', 'Melon');
```

Imagine we want to automate that prescription checkup by the patient:

```
$keys = array_rand($fruits, 3);     // get 3 random keys from your array    
foreach ($keys as $key) {          // cycle through the keys to get the values
    echo $fruits[$key] . "<br/>";
}
```

Sample output, a page that the patient checks anytime he wants:

```
Mango
Banana
Coconut
```

However, at this moment our code regenerates a new completely new combination after every refresh, confusing the patient! When the patient forgets what  three types he is limited to at this moment, the webpage should consistenly give the same three types, in the same order for a span of 12 hours. After that its allowed to generate a new random set.

How to solve the patients diet system with as little as extra code possible?

**Update!** preferably, no cookies or database etc: Furthermore: when the prescription page is visited by the Wife of the patient (who works outdoors and is very mobile using various computers) it should output the same three sets in same order as the patient. In other words: only constant is the time of the server.

Comment: generate a time stamp when the prescription is generated (for a specific user) and add 24 hours to it, store it in a db or something. only regenerate a new prescription if the time has been elapsed, it will check the time stamp vs the time it is on the server and create a new prescription if needed.

Comment: @Drewdin, you may want to post that as an answer.  By the way, are you Dr. Ewdin, practitioner of Fruit Therapy?  :)

Comment: @surreal, im scared to post answers. Every time i do i get down voted and lose points!

Comment: Don't be afraid.  I see most of your rep comes from questions (clearly, some good ones), but you've had plenty more up-votes than down.  That was a perfectly sensible answer.  Have faith in yourself, we welcome your contributions.

Comment: How, exactly, do you propose persistence be achieved if we can't use the persistence mechanisms modern browsers/servers offer?

Comment: @surreal, thanks. I'll start posting some answers, as you can see im a rookie and just getting started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a wierd solution, other than the obvious cookies or database answer.... Use a hash based on the date. This will change every 12 hours and each patient will get a different list based on their name (only works with an even 10 fruits, as is, but you could modify the concept to work with more)

```
<?
$fruits=array ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$patient_name = "bob";

$choices=array_slice(array_unique(str_split(preg_replace("/[a-z]/i","",md5(date("m/d/y a").$patient_name)))),0,3);

foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    echo $fruits[$choice] . "<br>";
}
```

p.s. This is a joke, kinda... Though, it will work for what you want, if you cant use cookies or a database.

**Edit:**

Why the snub sam... it really works!

http://www.ideone.com/HELVl Try it!

**@sam**

What is it doing? Basically, it takes an md5 hash of today's date, as well as the AM/PM for the current time (changes every 12 hours), and the users name.  Then it removes all the letters from the hash, so you're left with some 'random' numbers.  Then it turns the numbers into an array, with one number in each array item.  Then it slices the array to how many choices you want, in this case three.  Then with an array of those three numbers, you use loop through using them as keys for the fruits array.

The reason you could get only two (or less) results when you have six items only, is if the keys it chose are greater than five.  Which is why i said it works only with exactly 10 items.

Its a crazy solution, but I guess its gone this far so i'll explain further. To make it work with more items, you need two digits for your key, and preferably a fruit list with the count being a multiple of 10. Say you have 60 fruits, the last key in your fruit array would be 59. So you've already generated a 1's place digit from 0 to 9, now you need the 10's place digit from 0 to 5. So generate another hash, or use the reverse of the first one. You'd want to preg_replace [a-z][6-9], so your array of numbers you get back will only be numbers from 0-5 (you may want to use more hashes so you have a long enough string to make sure you get enough numbers). Then for your key, you'd do something like `$key=(int) $key1 . $key2;` to get the two digits you need.

Comment: Works well indeed! Thanks. I dont understand why but it does:) What do I have to change sothat It can work for more than ten? say 24 items in array like 32 or 64 items? I tried it with six items filled then it showed only two results. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'll edit it and add an explanation on how it works.  To make it work for more, you'll need a generate a 2nd digit for the key.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want minimal code changes possible, but for what its worth, I recommend persist data to a database when you need to hold it for long periods of time.

Should be very simple:

```
FruitRecommendations
--------------------
PatientId (fk int)
FruitId (fk int)
ExpirationDate datetime
```

When you select a set of fruit, insert into your database with ExpirationDate set to now()+24 hours.

You can get the latest fruit very easily as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM FruitRecommendations
WHERE
    PatientId = ? AND
    ExpirationDate < now()
ORDER BY ExpirationDate DESC
Limit 3
```

If that query returns 0 rows, you're free to select a new fruit combination and push those rows into your table.

Comment: Sounds like a very good porposal +1 pity herein cannot use a Database /cookies

Comment: Why can't you use a database, if I may ask?  not even an embedded database?

Comment: Embedded database? sounds interesting! Whats that? Hyperlink please thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

A cookie should do the trick.  When a "patient" visits the site, check to see if the cookie is set.  If it's set, display the contents of the cookie.  If it's not, choose a random set of fruit, assign the fruit to the cookie (setting 12 hours until the cookie expires), and display the fruit.  This won't take much PHP to accomplish and can be done in one simple file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [profitphp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867249/patient-docter-model-how-to-keep-random-generated-keys-of-an-array-for-12-hours/4867440#4867440) and the OPs comment that he can't use databases or cookies, you can do the following (sorry, don't know PHP, pseudocode should work):

- You can create a hash of the current date in 12hr format + patientID.
- Use said hash as a seed to a random number generator.
- Use rng to shuffle your array of fruits (don't know if php has a built-in shuffle, if not [this works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).
- Select first 3 elements from your shuffled array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "[silly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867249/patient-docter-model-how-to-keep-random-generated-keys-of-an-array-for-12-hours/4867440#4867440)" solution has it right. Since your question is based on 12 hour intervals, it's far easier to use the current time. This goes a step further, but is substantially simpler: Just seed the random number generator based on the remainder of the current time divided by 12 hours. This will be a new unique value every 12 hours, and will guarantee that your array shuffles to the same state for each 12 hour window.

```
srand(time() % (60 * 60 * 12));
```

Your code will work as posted, and return a new set of three fruits every 12 hours. The only "weakness" is that it won't begin counting from the date of the first visit.